# Gatling user injection in sequence

Tags: scala, gatling

I have 1 scenario that I'd like to test with different loads of users.

```
  val reports1 = createScenario("rep1")
  val reports2 = createScenario("rep2")
  val reports3 = createScenario("rep3")

  def createScenario(name: String) : ScenarioBuilder = {
    val newScenario = scenario(name)
    .exec(
      sse("My Scenario")
        .open("/endpoint")
        .headers(config.header))
    .exec(sse("close").close())

    newScenario
  }

  setUp(
    reports1.inject(
      atOnceUsers(1),
      nothingFor(2 minutes),
      atOnceUsers(10),
      nothingFor(5 minutes),
      atOnceUsers(50)
    ),
    reports2.inject(
      atOnceUsers(1),
      nothingFor(2 minutes),
      atOnceUsers(10),
      nothingFor(5 minutes),
      rampUsers(50) over(50 seconds)
    ))
    .protocols(http.baseURL(config.url))
```

When I run this, the injection is done in parallel.

I probably can merge all the user injections in 1 block and separate with a pause() but that doesn't seem like a nice solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injections are not done in parallel, scenarios are done in parallel. That's how Gatling is working - all scenarios passed as parameters of one `setUp()` call are always executed parallel, if you want them to run sequentially than each scenario should be in separate simulation class. Also your example kind of makes no sense since you run 2 scenarios that only differs in name, maybe I would recommend something else if you can provide real life example.

Comment: I run 2 similar scenarios so that I can inject users in a different way. The endpoint is the same but not the number of users. As I said I can merge both inject blocks into one. I'm just looking for a better way.

Comment: But if you will run those scenarios in parallel than you will just duplicate number of users in system and you will get same result as with one injection with higher values. Question is what you want to achieve?